How to create a custom scorecard in Dshborad module using JSON file data in Odoo 16?
I was trying to create a scorecard on a Dashboard module using Json file data.
Here is my Json file
*.js
        {

          "version":12,
          "sheets": [
            {
              "id":"Sheet1",
              "name":"My custom Sales Dashboard",

              "figures":[
                {
                    "id": "b9b862dd-1d57-47d9-b46c-ffcf4f8be638",
                    "x": 0,
                    "y": 178,
                    "width": 1000,
                    "height": 230,
                    "tag": "chart",
                    "data": {
                        "title": "",
                        "background": "#ffffff",
                        "legendPosition": "none",
                        "metaData": {
                            "groupBy": [
                                "create_date:month"
                            ],
                            "measure": "__count",
                            "order": null,
                            "resModel": "sale.order"
                        },
                        "searchParams": {
                            "comparison": null,
                            "context": {
                                "params": {
                                    "menu_id": 445,
                                    "cids": 1,
                                    "action": 737,
                                    "model": "sale.order",
                                    "view_type": "kanban"
                                },
                                "default_state": "sale",
                                "search_default_my_quotation": 1
                            },
                            "domain": [
                                [
                                    "state",
                                    "=",
                                    "sale"
                                ]
                            ],
                            "groupBy": [
                                "create_date:month"
                            ],
                            "orderBy": []
                        },
                        "type": "odoo_bar",
                        "verticalAxisPosition": "left"
                    }
                },
                {
                  "id":"26d0db83-eced-423a-83ba-143e890a45ee",
                  "x": 0,
                  "y": 0,
                  "width": 192,
                  "height": 120,
                  "tag": "chart",
                  "data": {
                      "baselineColorDown": "#DC6965",
                      "baselineColorUp": "#00A04A",
                      "baselineMode": "text",
                      "title": "MTD",
                      "type": "scorecard",
                      "background": "",
                      "baseline": "Data!E4",
                      "baselineDescr": "count",
                      "keyValue": "Data!D4"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "id":"26d0db83-eced-423a-83ba-143e890a45ff",
                  "x": 200,
                  "y": 0,
                  "width": 192,
                  "height": 120,
                  "tag": "chart",
                  "data": {
                      "baselineColorDown": "#DC6965",
                      "baselineColorUp": "#00A04A",
                      "baselineMode": "text",
                      "title": "MTD",
                      "type": "scorecard",
                      "background": "",
                      "baseline": "Data!E5",
                      "baselineDescr": "count",
                      "keyValue": "Data!E5"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "areGridLinesVisible": true,
              "isVisible": true

            },
            {
              "id": "d5999256-9e45-4b90-bce8-511f03087dfa",
              "name": "Data",
              "colNumber": 26,
              "rowNumber": 104,
              "rows": {
                  "4": {
                      "size": 23
                  }
              },
              "cols": {
                  "0": {
                      "size": 188
                  },
                  "1": {
                      "size": 157
                  },
                  "2": {
                      "size": 157
                  },
                  "3": {
                      "size": 157
                  },
                  "4": {
                      "size": 157
                  }
              },
              "merges": [],
              "cells":{
                "B1": {
                    "style": 7,
                    "content": "=ODOO.PIVOT(1,\"__count\")"
                },
                "B3": {
                    "style": 7,
                    "content": "=ODOO.PIVOT(4,\"order_id\")"
                },
                "B4": {
                    "style": 7,
                    "content": "=ODOO.PIVOT(1,\"amount_total\")"
                },
                "B2": {
                    "style": 7,
                    "format": 3,
                    "content": "=IFERROR(B)"
                },
                "D4": {
                    "style": 8,
                    "content": "=FORMAT.LARGE.NUMBER(B3)"
                },
                "E4": {
                    "style": 8,
                    "content": "=FORMAT.LARGE.NUMBER(B1)"
                },
                "E5": {
                    "style": 7,
                    "format": 3,
                    "content": "=ODOO.PIVOT(1,\"amount_total\")"
                }
              }

            }
          ],
          "odooVersion": 4,
          "styles": {
              "1": {
                  "textColor": "#01666b",
                  "bold": true,
                  "fontSize": 16
              },
              "2": {
                  "bold": true
              },
              "3": {
                  "fillColor": "#f8f9fa",
                  "textColor": "#741b47"
              },
              "4": {
                  "textColor": "#741b47"
              },
              "5": {
                  "bold": true,
                  "fontSize": 16
              },
              "6": {
                  "bold": true,
                  "align": "right"
              },
              "7": {
                  "fillColor": "#f8f9fa"
              },
              "8": {
                  "bold": true,
                  "fillColor": "#f8f9fa"
              }
          },
          "formats": {
              "1": "0",
              "2": "#,##0",
              "3": "#,##0.00",
              "4": "0.00%"
          },
          "pivots":{
            "1":{
              "context":{
                "default_state": "sale",
                "search_default_my_quotation": 1
              },
                "domain":[
                  ["state","=","sale"]
                ],
                "id":"1",
                "measures": [
                  {
                    "field": "__count"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "amount_total"
                  }

                ],
                "model":"sale.order",
                "rowGroupBys": [
                    "state"
                ],
                "name": "sale order count",
                "sortedColumn": null
            },
            "4": {
                "colGroupBys": [],
                "context": {},
                "domain": [],
                "id": "4",
                "measures": [
                    {
                        "field": "order_id"
                    }
                ],
                "model": "sale.order",
                "rowGroupBys": [],
                "name": "stats - current"
            }
          },
          "pivotNextId": 15,
          "globalFilter":[
            {
              "id": "77bc36ef-1319-4784-891f-950545059abe",
              "type": "date",
              "label": "Period",
              "defaultValue": "last_year",
              "rangeType": "relative",
              "defaultsToCurrentPeriod": false,
              "pivotFields": {
                  "1": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": 0
                  },
                  "2": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": -1
                  },
                  "3": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": 0
                  },
                  "4": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": -1
                  },
                  "5": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": 0
                  },
                  "6": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": -1
                  },
                  "7": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": 0
                  },
                  "8": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": 0
                  },
                  "9": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": 0
                  },
                  "10": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": 0
                  },
                  "11": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": 0
                  },
                  "12": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": 0
                  },
                  "13": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": 0
                  },
                  "14": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": 0
                  }
              },
              "listFields": {},
              "graphFields": {
                  "b9b862dd-1d57-47d9-b46c-ffcf4f8be638": {
                      "field": "create_date",
                      "type": "datetime",
                      "offset": 0
                  }
              }
            }
          ]
        }

The custom module was installed and worked successfully. But the value on the score card shows #ERROR instead of a value.
Here I am attaching the screenshot.

How can I solve this?
